# Jquery how to check if all inputs have values or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal, where the user can fill out a form. When the user, for some reason decides to abort filling out the form and clicks on the close button, the user will get an alert like "are you sure? all data will be lost!"

So far it works fine, but when nothing is entered and the user closes the modal, the alert with the message still shows up, how can I avoid this? or maybe even better - can I approve my validation?

```
$('#uploadModal [data-btn="close-modal"]').on("click", e => {
   if ($(".text-success").is(":visible")) {
       $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
   } else {
       let validate = false;
       $("#uploadModal .form-row").each(function() {
          if (
            $("#uploadModal .form-row input").val() != "" ||
            $("#uploadModal .form-row input[type=file]").val() != "" ||
            $("#uploadModal .form-row textarea").val() != "" ||
            $("#uploadModal .form-row select").val() != "" ||
            $("#uploadModal .form-row input").attr("checked")
          )
            validate = true;
       });

       if (!validate) {
           $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
       } else {
           if (confirm("Are you sure? All entered data will be lost")) {
               $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
           }
       }
   }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since many asks, I really just use a lot of simple `input`-fields

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
<input type="file" name="attachment" placeholder="Files" />
<textarea name="bio" placeholder="your bio"><textarea/>
<input type="checkbox" name="current" />
```

thats all there is, I don't use `required` on any of them

Comment: Please share your html as well. You probably want to change `$("#uploadModal .form-row input")` to `$(this).find("input")` to validate the row of the current iteration.

Comment: there is a required attribute in html that prevents submitting of your form if not filled in. Can you improve you code? Absolutely yes.

Comment: you could have a boolean variable thats always false unless any input, textarea or select is focussed. And it has to be reseted after canceling, if its still false on validation you can just skip the confirm as the user did not do anything yet

Comment: You can use !!$("#uploadModal .form-row input").val() to check if field is "falsy". There is a chance that field is initiated as undefined.

Comment: remove the data-dismiss attributes from the buttons and just call the hide method on the modal object from your code. What modal library are you using?

Comment: Had a solution but @MarkBaijens wanted it to delete it so, i'm sorry.

Comment: @Wimanicesir Sorry if you feel offended, it was meant as constructive feedback to improve the posts on SO. Wasn't my intention to let you delete it but to improve it since it was not doing what the OP asked for. You where on the right direction but not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain another variable for all the empty values, based on which you can show the message:

```
$('#uploadModal [data-btn="close-modal"]').on("click", e => {
  if ($(".text-success").is(":visible")) {
    $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
  } else {
   let validate = false;
   let allEmpty = false;
   $("#uploadModal .form-row").each(function() {
      if (
        $("#uploadModal .form-row input").val() != "" ||
        $("#uploadModal .form-row input[type=file]").val() != "" ||
        $("#uploadModal .form-row textarea").val() != "" ||
        $("#uploadModal .form-row select").val() != "" ||
        $("#uploadModal .form-row input").attr("checked")
      )
        validate = true;
      else if(
        $("#uploadModal .form-row input").val() == "" &&
        $("#uploadModal .form-row input[type=file]").val() == "" &&
        $("#uploadModal .form-row textarea").val() == "" &&
        $("#uploadModal .form-row select").val() == "" &&
        !$("#uploadModal .form-row input").("checked")
      )
       allEmpty = true;
   });

   if (!validate) {
       $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
   } else if(!allEmpty) {
       if (confirm("Are you sure? All entered data will be lost")) {
           $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
       }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @ST80, without the relevant HTML it is really difficult to come up with the accurate solution....

Comment: Please check my updated question - thats all there is

Comment: @ST80, I really meant the minimum executable code:)

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved it myself by doing this ( thanks to @Mamum's suggestion)

The code now looks like this:

```
$('#uploadModal [data-btn="close-modal"]').on("click", e => {
   if ($(".text-success").is(":visible")) {
       $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
   } else {
       let validate = false;
       let allEmpty = false;
       $("#uploadModal").each(function() {
           if (
               $("#uploadModal .form-row input").val().length > 0 ||
               $("#uploadModal .form-row input[type=file]").val().length > 0 ||
               $("#uploadModal .form-row textarea").val().length > 0 ||
               $("#uploadModal .form-row input[type=checkbox]:checked").length
           ) {
               validate = true;
           } else if (
               $("#uploadModal .form-row input").val().length == 0 &&
               $("#uploadModal .form-row input[type=file]").val().length ==
                0 &&
               $("#uploadModal .form-row textarea").val().length == 0 &&
               $("#uploadModal .form-row input[type=checkbox]:checked")
                .length == 0
           ) {
               allEmpty = true;
           }
       });

       if (!validate) {
           $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
       } else if (!allEmpty) {
           if (confirm("Are you sure? All entered data will be lost")) {
               $('#uploadModal [data-dismiss="modal"]').click();
           }
       }
   }
});
```

Hope this may help or at least inspire someone, who might end up in the same situation.